# Laravel Nova authorization using Policy is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am developing a web application using Laravel. I am using Nova for admin panel. What I am doing now is I am authorizing my resource using policies as mentioned in the documentation. But seems like it is not working. This is what I have done so far. I have created a nova resource like this.

```
class Item extends Resource
{
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = \App\Models\Item::class;

    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'id';

    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [
        'id',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cards available for the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the lenses available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function lenses(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the actions available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Then I created a Laravel Model class for that resource with the name Item.

Then I created policy.

```
class ItemPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function view(User $user, $item)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function update(User $user, $item)
    {

        return false;
    }

    public function delete(User $user, $item)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function restore(User $user, $item)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function forceDelete(User $user, $item)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I register the policy in the in AuthServiceProvider.

```
protected $policies = [

    Item::class => ItemPolicy::class,
];
```

When I see the list of item in the nova admin panel, I can still create the item. What is wrong? The option for creating an item should be hidden.

Comment: Double check if the class namespace is correct under `AuthServiceProvider` class. `AuthServiceProvider` doesn't throw any exception even if the model/ policy class doesn't exists.

Comment: @Wai Yan Hein, Have you resolved this issue? I am also getting the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your Nova resource class:

```
public static function authorizable()
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check AuthServiceProvider once again.

where you define the policy mapping array:

```
protected $policies = [
    Item::class => ItemPolicy::class,
];
```

The **Item** - should be your **Model**, not **Nova Resource**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `viewAny()` method from the `ItemPolicyPolicy` class

Answer (score 0):

Using rolePolicy or permissionPolicy method to define policy

```
// in app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php

// ...

public function tools()
{
    return [
        // ...
        \Vyuldashev\NovaPermission\NovaPermissionTool::make()
            ->rolePolicy(RolePolicy::class)
            ->permissionPolicy(PermissionPolicy::class),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your registered your policy wrong

```
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Item' => 'App\Policies\ItemPolicy',
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because you are missing model type in method arguments

Add `Item $item` in all methods where passing $item, like this:

```
public function update(User $user, Item $item)
{
    return false;
}
```

Also you can exclude all methods you want to be unavailable and by default them will be disabled

Comment: No. I put the Type to every method. But it is still displaying the option to create. For example, I just want to hide the create option. But it is still displaying even if I returned false from the create method.